# mysql like statement is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with 4 record.

```
Records: 1) arup Sarma
         2) Mitali Sarma
         3) Nisha
         4) haren Sarma
```

And I used the below SQL statement to get records from a search box.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM ".user_table." WHERE name LIKE '%$q' LIMIT 5";
```

But this retrieve all records from the table. Even if I type a non-existence word (eg.: hgasd or anything), it shows all the 4 record above. Where is the problem ? plz any advice..

This is my full code:

```
$q = ucwords(addslashes($_POST['q']));
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM ".user_table." WHERE name LIKE '%".$q."' LIMIT 5";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$q` has a value?  Can you try a `var_dump($q)`?  How are you populating that variable?

Comment: can you print out the rendered string to ensure that the $q variable isn't the issue?

Comment: @smp7d I var_dump and found this : string(0) "" . but there is already a post data....

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what it says.  In particular, are you really submitting the form using the POST method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is fine. Your problem is that $q does not have any value or you are appending the value incorrectly to your query, so you are effectively doing:

```
"SELECT id,name FROM ".user_table." WHERE name LIKE '%' LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: You did not comment on the SQL-injection issues, the OP edited in that code **after** your answer so I'm not downvoting for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to
**A - Prevent SQL-injection**
**B - Prevent like with an empty $q**

```
//$q = ucwords(addslashes($_POST['q']));
//Addslashes does not work to prevent SQL-injection!
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q']);
if (isset($q)) {
  $sql = "SELECT id,name FROM user_table WHERE name LIKE '%$q' 
          ORDER BY id DESC
          LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "id: ".htmlentities($row['id']);
    echo "name: ".htmlentities($row['name']);
  }
} else { //$q is empty, handle the error }
```

A few comments on the code.

1. If you are not using PDO, but mysql instead, only mysql_real_escape_string will protect you from SQL-injection, nothing else will.
2. Always surround any `$vars` you inject into the code with single `'` quotes.  If you don't the escaping will not work and syntax error will hit you.
3. You can test an var with `isset` to see if it's filled.
4. Why are you concatenating the tablename? Just put the name of the table in the string as usual.
5. If you only select a few rows, you really need an `order by` clause so the outcome will not be random, here I've order the newest id, assuming `id` is an auto_increment field, newer id's will represent newer users.
6. If you echo data from the database, you need to escape that using `htmlentities` to prevent XSS security holes.

Answer (score -1):

In mysql, like operator use '$' regex to represent end of any string.. and '%' is for beginning.. so any string will fall under this regex, that's why it returms all records. 
Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html once. Hope, this will help you.

Comment: +1 for the link, -1 for not actually reading what it says.  (Hint: `REGEXP`and `LIKE` are not the same thing.)